# Implementing a reusable @Controller

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I'm implementing [some SQL-CRUD components for Spring-MVC](https://github.com/alexpdp7/jcrud) and I'm facing a problem.

I provide a [`TableController`](https://github.com/alexpdp7/jcrud/blob/master/jcrud/src/main/java/net/pdp7/jcrud/TableController.java) which provides several controller methods:

```
public class TableController ... {

    public TableController(String tableName) { ... }

    @RequestMapping("/list")
    public ModelAndView list() { ... }

    @RequestMapping("/addForm")
    public ModelAndView addForm() { ... }
    ...
```

This `TableController` basically provides functionality over a database table- a controller method that lists the table's rows, forms for creating and updating table rows, etc. It is a somewhat complex class, as it needs to be customizable to offer different behaviour for different tables.

Ideally, I would like users of this controller to be able to add a new instance for each database table they want to expose in their website by adding it to a context, something like this:

```
@Configuration
class Context {
    @Bean("/vets/")
    public TableController vetController() {
        return new TableController("vets");
    }

    @Bean("/pets/")
    public TableController petController() {
        return new TableController("pets");
    }
```

I would expect then to get `/vets/list`, `/vets/addForm`, `/pets/list` URLs exposed in their app.

However, this does not work. The only way I've gotten this to work is by not using *any* `@RequestMapping` annotation in `TableController` and having the apps extend `TableController` for each table they want to expose and define *all* `@RequestMapping`s in the subclasses, what I'm doing for instance in [`Application`](https://github.com/alexpdp7/jcrud/blob/master/petclinic/src/main/java/net/pdp7/jcrud/petclinic/Application.java) and [`PetController`](https://github.com/alexpdp7/jcrud/blob/master/petclinic/src/main/java/net/pdp7/jcrud/petclinic/PetController.java)

This works but it's extremely awkward. Any way to improve this?

Edit: it seems that I'm fucked:

> There are also several things no longer possible:
>
> - Select a controller first with a SimpleUrlHandlerMapping or BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping and then narrow the method based on
>     @RequestMapping annotations.

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-requestmapping-31-vs-30

Comment: Take a look at Spring Data Rest.

Comment: @Evgeni AFAIK Spring Data Rest only produces JSON, or am I wrong ?

Answer (score 2):

What you need is only one "@TableController" with dynamic "@RequestMapping". Use a variable, path or request, to identify the database table or entity and build the query accordingly. You can even mix this with the logged in user to build restrictions for example.

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/{tablename}")
public class TableController ... {


    public TableController() { ... }

    @RequestMapping("/list")
    public ModelAndView list(@PathVariable("tablename") String tablename) { ... }

    @RequestMapping("/addForm")
    public ModelAndView addForm(@PathVariable("tablename") String tablename) { ... }
    ...
```

Read the javadoc of "@RequestMapping" and "@Controller". They support quite a lot of variable types.

Comment: +1. I've been using this pattern and it works great. Note that it can get pretty reflection-heavy since it often involves building a meta-model by scanning entity and repo classes for annotations. Spring Data REST uses this approach as well; see their GitHub site for details.

Comment: That could work, but I'd rather have one `TableController` per database table- it makes the implementation much simpler as I need to offer customization options per-table (e.g. customize the widgets used to edit specific columns, handle inline editing of related tables, etc.).

Comment: @alex i see your point. I implemented this type of customization by using a configuration delegate base on the given parameter. "getConfig(tablename).getEditorFragment()" for example. I don't know if you can find a way to register controllers dynamically. "RequestMapping" does nothing else, but i don't know if the registry is open to be used by application code. Then you could just create controller beans based on one loop through your table names. If each one needs customization anyway your code as you have it should be the way to go i think.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried to add the `@RequestMapping` annotation to the class level of the subclasses? By doing so, the other `@RequestMapping` annotations in the `TableController` should become relative. There will still be one class per table, but it becomes really trivial. Example:

```
// No @RequestMapping on class level
public abstract class TableController {
    // all methods annotated with @RequestMapping that will be relative once inherited
}
```

First actual controller

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/vets")
public class VetController extends TableController {

    public VetController() {
        super("vets");
    }

    // other methods and relative @RequestMapping omitted since they are inherited from parent class 
}
```

Second controller

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/pets")
public class PetController extends TableController {

    public PetController() {
        super("pets");
    }

    // other methods and relative @RequestMapping omitted since they are inherited from parent class 
}
```

More info about the `@RequestMapping` can be found in Spring's [reference documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-requestmapping).